Google Cloud Trigger a job task which uses GPU using an http request and no GKE
Using Google Cloud, is there a way to trigger a task of a job using GPUs?
My use case is that I need to run Deep Learning models in images using GPUs, but they are sporadic, and they are normally called by a user who selects an image to use the model on and then a compute resource fetches the item, runs the model and saves results.
This is not a duplicate of this question, I don't want to have a bloated possibly expensive solution, I don't need Kubernetes, no GKE etc.
If anything, this is a better resource: Starting and stopping a Compute VM
Where a single VM is turned on when needed.
But I am wondering what is the best way to cover this use case where a GPU is needed only for a short time, only a few times per year.
Can someone please give me any pointers on how to do this?
I have read cloud.google.com/batch/docs/create-run-job-gpus but as I mention it only explains how to schedule it.

See the non-accepted but upvoted answer here and the link to this documentation in it.

It is not an answer. Just a link. And it must be possible to do this without a GKE cluster. One doesn't have to become a Kubernetes expert to use a GPU in seldom cases. I'm asking for another possible workflow, perhaps not involving GKE, Knative, dockers, not serverless. So please don't just close the question. I've been through this documentation, the answer is not there which is why I came to SO, looking for input. It is not a duplicate...

It really seems like the same question to me, you just want a different answer than those given there. If it is possible in a different way than described in the answer to the question I linked, that way would also be a valid answer there. If you disagree that this is a duplicate, you can vote to reopen your question.
